# How to display latest('updated_at') records in blade file of laravel

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am doing project in laravel. In my project there are two tables categories and subcategories. subcategories table has categoryid as foreign key.

**subcategoryModel.php** has following function

```
public function category(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}
```

In my blade file I am displaying my subcategories using category object as follows,

**blade.php**

```
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-align-left">
        @foreach($category as $c)
             <div class="form-group clearfix">
                   @if($c->subcategories->count() > 0)
                   <h4><b>Subcategories: </b></h4>
                   <div class="form-group clearfix">
                    @foreach($c->subcategories as $subcategory)
                        <h4>{{$subcategory->subcategoryname}}</h4>
                    @endforeach
                   </div>
                   @endif
      <h4><a href="{{ url('subcategories/'.$c->categoryid.'') }}" class =        "btn btn-primary">Add Subcategories</a></h4>
     </div>
    @endforeach
    </div>
```

This display correct data,but now I want to display data in the order they are updated/created. Is there any way to display data as per the requirement?
I want to something into the blade file itself. How to do this? Please give suggestions.

Comment: I recommend to use @milan way which avoid N+1 problem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@foreach($c->subcategories()->orderBy('updated_at','asc')->get() as $subcategory)
     <h4>{{$subcategory->subcategoryname}}</h4>
@endforeach
```

Edit: I do like the other answer however OP asked for within the blade file itself

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't do something like that in a blade. Blade should be kept as dumb as possible. Main things should be done in the controller and then passed to the blade. you can do this in your controller:

```
    $categories = Category::with(array('subcategories' => function($query) {
        $query->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
    }))->get();
```

now the subcategories in the category object will be ordered.